# JavaScript operators precedence algorithm

Tags: javascript

I have an example:

```
let x = 4
console.log(x++ + ++x + x--)
```

it's returns `16` but I don't understand how.
If we will look in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) there is an operators precedence table.
So there is a precedence like this:

1. Postfix increment
2. Postfix decrement
3. Prefix increment
4. Addition

With this logic it should return `14`

1. `x++` = 4 - (5) -> remembers for next call
2. `x--` = 5 - (4) -> remembers for next call
3. `++x` = 5
4. `+`

`4 + 5 + 5 = 14`

Can some one explain, how operators parser algorithm works with unary and binary operators?

Comment: It is evaluated as `((x++) + (++x)) + (x--)`, which is `4 + 6 + 6` which is `16`.

Comment: You're not applying the prefix correctly - you'd get `4 + 6` not `4 + 5`

Comment: I guess you are assuming that order doesn't matter because `+`, but that is not the case. `x++ + x-- + ++x` is indeed 14, but `x++ + ++x + x--` is 16

Comment: Use astexplorer.net to check the order of execution: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/beee0ccc850f3621b2b9e4d493ff2c2b/f22aeb17531452c8d92ca86d3d6082a54730d344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is completely consistent. You are evaluating left-to-right and apply the precedence. I'll break it down in steps:

## 1. Post-increment `x++`

```
//x = 4
x++ + ++x + x--
^^^
  |
  --> expression = 4
  --> x = 5
```

First off we evaluate `x++`. Postfix increment has higher precedence than the addition, so we have to solve it first. This expression produces `4` (value of `x` at the time) however, the value of `x` is also incremented for future reads.

## 2. Pre-increment `++x`

```
//x = 5
4 + ++x + x--
    ^^^
      |
      --> x = 6
      --> expression = 5
```

Next `++x` is evaluated, as prefix increment also has higher precedence than the addition, so we have to resolve it before the expression `a + b`. We aren't concerned with `x--` yet, since we've not gotten to it.

Thus, the prefix increment will *increase* the value of `x` from `5` to `6` and then return that new value.

## 3. Addition `(x++) + (++x)`

```
//x = 6
4 + 6 + x--
^^^^^
    |
    --> expression = 10
```

We've resolved the higher priority expressions, so it's time for the addition. Which is simple `4 + 6 = 10`.

## 4. Post-decrement `x--`

```
//x = 6
10 + x--
     ^^^
       |
       --> expression = 6
       --> x = 5
```

We're reached another `a + b` construct but the postfix decrement `x--` is higher priority, so we solve that first. Current value of `x` is `6` and we return that, then do the decrement of `x` to `5`.

## 5. Addition `((x++) + (++x)) + (x--)`

```
//x = 5
10 + 6
^^^^^^
     |
     --> expression = 16
```

Finally, another simple addition after everything with higher precedence is resolved: `10 + 6 = 16`

Answer (score 4):

Once operator precedence is applied, the grouping looks like:

```
((x++) + (++x)) + (x--)
```

The interpreter will evaluate the two `+`s left-to-right, and resolve the inner expressions *as it comes across them.* The increments/decrements don't run *immediately* and before the `+`s - they only run once the interpreter has determined that their expression needs to be evaluated. This is what happens, in order:

```
x is 4
((x++) + (++x)) + (x--)


evaluate postfix increment: insert 4, x increases to 5
(4 + (++x)) + (x--)


evaluate prefix increment: x increases to 6, insert 6
(4 + 6) + (x--)

simplify:
10 + (x--)


evaluate postfix decrement: insert 6, x decreases to 5
10 + 6
```

Resulting in a final value of 16.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a table for the values, one for `x` with values for the actual/post or pre and actual value.

Then take according to the order of opperends the value and add this values.

```
let x = 4
console.log(x++ + ++x + x--); // 16
            post  pre   post  increment
x           4 5   5 6   6 5   different values
value       4       6   6     values for addition
```

```js
let x = 4
console.log(x++ + ++x + x--); // 16
```